# Bash-MySQL / try to insert string to table

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I try to insert string to mysql in bash, so I do the next:

```
message="<a href = http://www."
message="$message ${d}"
message="$message .com"
mysql -u root -pmypass -Bse 'INSERT INTO atTable VALUES (null, "'$message'")'
```

When I do it, I get the next massage:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.69, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
  -A, --no-auto-rehash
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      (Enables --silent.)
  --character-sets-dir=name
                      Directory for character set files.
```

and other commands. What I do wrong?

Comment: You're missing the database argument. Also, do you really want a space after `www.` and before `.com`?

Comment: Although when I try what you've written, the error I get is `ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected`

Comment: @Barmar: It something with the "'$message'". When I change it to "blabla" for example, everything its OK.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with this one:

```
message="<a href = http://www."
message="$message ${d}"
message="$message .com"
mysql -u root -pmypass -Bse "INSERT INTO atTable VALUES (null, '$message')";
```

At least it worked for me, when I tested it with this:

```
message="<a href = http://www."
message="$message hello"
message="$message .com"
mysql -u root -pwhatever -Bse "SELECT '$message'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysql -u root -pmypass -Bse "INSERT INTO atTable VALUES (null, '$message')"
```

The problem was the spaces in `$message` were ending the `-e` option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of piecing together the `message` variable like you did, this is easier to read:

   ```
   message="<a href = http://www. $d .com"
   ```

   This is equivalent to the example in the original post, though the text itself doesn't look meaningful.
2. You can pass your query to `mysql` like this:

   ```
   mysql -u root -pmypass -Bse  "INSERT INTO atTable VALUES (null, '$message')"
   ```
3. If `message` contains single quotes, you need to escape them, you can do like this:

   ```
   message=$(echo "$message" | sed -e "s/'/\\\\'/")
   ```
4. Instead of putting your root password on the command line, I recommend to put that information in the `.my.cnf` file of your home directory, for example:

   ```
   [client]
   database=yourdbname
   user=root
   password=yourpass
   ```

   **However,** *before* entering the real password, protect the file first like this:

   ```
   touch .my.cnf
   chmod 600 .my.cnf
   ```